# Create float from String

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex `\d+(?:[.,]\d+` that matches decimal strings with either dot or comma, like `123.123` or `123,123` so the value is valid.

Now my problem is to generate a Float value from the String which is either `123.123` or `123,123`

Comment: `Float#parseFloat()`. Don't know if it'll work for the comma, though...

Comment: I suggest you not use `Float` or `float` if you can avoid it, try using `double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code.

```
String val = "123.123 ";
float f = Float.parseFloat(val);

String val = "123,123 "; // if other char(like comma) come, you can also write a regex to replace those set of char
val = val.replace(",",".");// assuming comma is used for decimals
float f = Float.parseFloat(val);
```

Comment: Hmmm, wonder if the comma here is being used for a thousands separator or a decimal place...

Comment: I'm almost sure it's used for decimals.